# Submit a form or simulate enter / return being pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I know, with jQuery, it is possible to check a checkbox, but us it possible to submit a form. Not handle the submission / submitted data, but simulate the submit button being clicked— or if possible the enter / return key being pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and you don't even need the button:

```
$("form").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit_btn_id').click(function() {
    $('#form_id').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the submit button then you can emulate by using trigger in some other event's code.

```
 $('#submit_button_id').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course but you need to specify an even at which you want to simulate the action .
 I suppose that you want it to be the press of enter key .. the code will be

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
if (e.which == 13){
    $("#submit").trigger('click');
}
});

$("#submit").click(function(){

  // do your stuff
 })
```